# cant get date in right order for search

Tags: php, cakephp

I am not getting the date to be formatted when entering in the date.  I need it in year,month,day format but it is entered in from a form in month,day,year.
I get an error when searching for the date as I cant it in the right order  . I am sure there is an easy answer but I cant find it . It works when I set the date manually.

```
date is set like this by default.
array(
    'month' => '12',
    'day' => '01',
    'year' => '2015'
)
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

         //   debug( $this->request->data );
            $sdate=$this->request->data['Lesson']['lesson_date'];
             $edate=$this->request->data['Lesson']['lesson_date2'];
         //   $sdate='2012-04-04';  //correct format
         //    $edate='2015-04-04';


              debug($sdate);
            debug($edate);

              $options['conditions'] = array('Tutor.id'  => 2,
               'and' => array(
                        array('lesson_date >= ' => $sdate,
                              'lesson_date <= ' => $edate)));


              $tutor=$this->set( 'tutor',$this->Lesson->find('all', $options));


         }

//view
    echo $this->Form->create();



echo $this->Form->input(
    'lesson_date',
    array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'selected' => array(
            'year'=>date('Y')
        ),
        'dateFormat' => 'YMD',
        'minYear' => date('Y') ,
        'maxYear' => date('Y') +1
    )
);         


echo $this->Form->input(
    'lesson_date2',
    array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'selected' => array(
            'year'=>date('Y')
        ),
        'dateFormat' => 'YMD',
        'minYear' => date('Y') ,
        'maxYear' => date('Y') +1
    )
);   

                    echo $this->Form->end('Custom Search');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in our date option array: `dateFormat` if you want Y-m-d format

```
'dateFormat' => 'YMD'
```

You can set `dateformat` to following values: 'DMY', 'MDY', 'YMD' or 'NONE'.

[**More Detials**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements)

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work.Error: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s). I added in the line in the question above. Thhe error is in the find where it doesnt like this input and hence the question . I should not get a -1 for this as it isnt obvious

Comment: You also need to add this line else it wont work in the find . you need to parse the date into a string manually $startd=$sdate['year'] . '-' .$sdate['month']. '-' .$sdate['day'];